# Search Field and Show Entry miss-aligned jquery table with Bootstrap5 theme

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I'm having some trouble with making a simple DataTable with Bootstrap 5 theme. The main issue is that the "show Entry" and "Search bar" are missaligned as well as the page part at the bottom of the table (best seen in the picture bellow). I have to mentioned that if I use other styles, they are alligned. The issue is only for bootstrap 5 themed DataTables

[Snip Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXxBO.png)

I have included all the necessary plugins:

```
<!--css plugins for table-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css">


<!--js plugins for table-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
```

The html part for the table is pretty basic:

```
<section class="container shadow">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="lista_proiecte" class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Judet</th>
                        <th>Localitate principala</th>
                        <th>Siruta superioara</th>
                        <th>Localitati apartenente </th>
                        <th>Sirute inferioare</th>
                        <th>Tipul solicitarii</th>
                        <th>Data intrare</th>
                        <th>Ultimul status</th>
                        <th>Utilizator</th>
                        <th>Deadline</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
</section>
```

The table is autofilled from SQL database using AJAX. I'm not so sure if it makes a difference but I'll put it here.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var dataTable = $('#lista_proiecte').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "order":[],
    "ajax":{
        url:"php/acasa_listaproiecte_fetch.php",
        type:"POST",
        
    },

    "lengthMenu": [ [10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"] ],
    
    createdRow:function(row, data, rowIndex)
    {
        $.each($('td', row), function(colIndex){
            if(colIndex == 1)
            {
                $(this).attr('data-name', 'judet');
                $(this).attr('class', 'judet');
                $(this).attr('data-type', 'text');
                $(this).attr('data-pk', data[0]);
            }
            if(colIndex == 2)
            {
                $(this).attr('data-name', 'localitate_principala');
                $(this).attr('class', 'localitate_principala');
                $(this).attr('data-type', 'text');
                $(this).attr('data-pk', data[0]);
            }
            if(colIndex == 3)
            {
                $(this).attr('data-name', 'siruta_superioara');
                $(this).attr('class', 'siruta_superioara');
                $(this).attr('data-type', 'text');
                $(this).attr('data-pk', data[0]);
            }
            if(colIndex == 4)
            {
                $(this).attr('data-name', 'localitati_apartenente');
                $(this).attr('class', 'localitati_apartenente');
                $(this).attr('data-type', 'text');
                $(this).attr('data-pk', data[0]);
            }
            if(colIndex == 5)
            {
                $(this).attr('data-name', 'sirute_inferioare');
                $(this).attr('class', 'sirute_inferioare');
                $(this).attr('data-type', 'text');
                $(this).attr('data-pk', data[0]);
            }
            if(colIndex == 6)
            {
                $(this).attr('data-name', 'tip_solicitare');
                $(this).attr('class', 'tip_solicitare');
                $(this).attr('data-type', 'text');
                $(this).attr('data-pk', data[0]);
            }
            if(colIndex == 7)
            {
                $(this).attr('data-name', 'data_intrare');
                $(this).attr('class', 'data_intrare');
                $(this).attr('data-type', 'text');
                $(this).attr('data-pk', data[0]);
            }
            if(colIndex == 8)
            {
                $(this).attr('data-name', 'ultimul_status');
                $(this).attr('class', 'ultimul_status');
                $(this).attr('data-type', 'text');
                $(this).attr('data-pk', data[0]);
            }
            if(colIndex == 9)
            {
                $(this).attr('data-name', 'nume_utilizator');
                $(this).attr('class', 'nume_utilizator');
                $(this).attr('data-type', 'text');
                $(this).attr('data-pk', data[0]);
            }
            if(colIndex == 10)
            {
                $(this).attr('data-name', 'deadline');
                $(this).attr('class', 'deadline');
                $(this).attr('data-type', 'text');
                $(this).attr('data-pk', data[0]);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example works well with Bootstrap 5 Theme.
I did a jsfiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/bogatyr77/g7ntd8rk/8/
Just play with the Result window and you see the Search and the other Stuff is well adjusted.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#lista_proiecte').DataTable({
    ajax: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bmehler/employees/main/personal",
    "lengthMenu": [
      [10, 25, 50, -1],
      [10, 25, 50, "All"]
    ],
    "columns": [{
        "data": "id"
      },
      {
        "data": "name"
      },
      {
        "data": "job"
      }
    ],
    "createdRow": function(row, data, dataIndex) {
      $.each($('td', row), function(colIndex) {
        if (colIndex == 1) {
          $(this).attr('data-name', 'judet');
          $(this).attr('class', 'judet');
          $(this).attr('data-type', 'text');
          $(this).attr('data-pk', data.job);
        }
      });
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="container shadow">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="lista_proiecte" class="table table-striped table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Judet</th>
          <th>Localitate principala</th>
          <th>Siruta superioara</th>
          <th>Localitati apartenente </th>
          <th>Sirute inferioare</th>
          <th>Tipul solicitarii</th>
          <th>Data intrare</th>
          <th>Ultimul status</th>
          <th>Utilizator</th>
          <th>Deadline</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thx. I played with the packagase from DataTables and somehow managed to make the look good. So I assume for the rest checking this topic, make sure you have the right js and css files included in the correct order